# Strange behaviour of Locale Class or DateTimeFormatter(java8)

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, locale, datetime-format

I am writing a Date-Time wrapper for my project using Java8 `java.time` package in which user will pass me a pattern,language and his timezone id (eg. `Asia/Kolkatta`, etc) on the basis of which i will output the LocalDateTime object(as String) as per his preferred timezone.So basically I have this method signature in mind

```
public static String getDateTime(String pattern, String language, String timezone){}
```

For getting timezone preffered time i have used `ZonedDateTime` which is working fine but I am facing a strange behaviour for getting language plus pattern specific format. I am using 
`public static DateTimeFormatter ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`  I just tried with basic example to go ahead before writing any concrete structure but I am getting different results for same operation. Check below mentioned 2 programs-

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lang = "hi";    
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm", new Locale("hi","IN"));
        System.out.println("Date:"+ LocalDateTime.now().format(dateTimeFormatter));
      }
```

**Output:**

```
Date:16-अगस्त-2016,14:30
```

Now here I am getting the expected output for Locale in (Hindi,India) but now when I thought of optimising it by using the already available locale objects rather than using `new Locale(String language, String country)` I am not getting the result, I did something like this:

```
            public class App2 {
              // using map to act as a cache for the Key:Language and Value: Locale 
              private static Map<String,Locale> localeMap = new HashMap<String, Locale>();

              public static void main(String[] args) {
                String lang = "hi";
                if (localeMap.get(lang) == null) {
                  for (Locale locale1 : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
                    if (locale1.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
             System.out.println("Lang:"+locale1.getLanguage()+",Country:"+locale1.getCountry());
             localeMap.put(lang, locale1);
                    }
                  }
                }
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm", localeMap.get(lang));
                System.out.println("Date:"+ LocalDateTime.now().format(dateTimeFormatter));
              }
            }
```

**Output:**

```
    Lang:hi,Country:IN
    Lang:hi,Country:
    Date:16-Aug-2016,15:18
```

**Note:**

1. Locale corresponding to `"hi"` is already present in

   for (Locale locale1 : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
           if (locale1.getLanguage().equals("hi")) is not null
   }

**Questions:**

1. Any reason why different output for above mentioned methods ? - Resolved [there were multiple entries for locales where lang is:"hi"]
2. I also wants to know why I am not getting numbers in that language. I am getting month name in hindi(for `new Locale("hi","IN")`) but not the numbers in date and time.(eg. I want numbers in ०,१,२,३,४,५,६,७,८,९,१० - this is hindi version of 0,1,2,3,4..10)
3. I also observed if I log locale1.getLanguage and locale1.getCountry(), 2 entries are there lang:hi and Country:IN and lang:hi and country:" "(empty string) and same for other locales too I observe this behaviour(language is there but no country). Any reasons ?

Edit1:
 After putting sopln while insertion in map, I see there are two locales for which language is hindi if put an additional check in that for loop `!locale1.getCountry().isEmpty() && locale1.getLanguage().equals(lang)` ; I am getting the expected output. Now in Locale class there is constructor for Locale(String language) also. It also doesn't seem to work for "hi" but for "zh" - which is for CHINESE it works which gives multiple entries for zh and locale objects and for last insertion country has empty value which is similar to "hi" behaviour but yet I get an output in Chinese. Basically,this points to 3 in questions to ask.

```
Lang:zh,Country:TW
Lang:zh,Country:HK
Lang:zh,Country:SG
Lang:zh,Country:CN
Lang:zh,Country:
Date:16-八月-2016,17:14
```

Comment: Well for the locale you've put in your map, what country are you seeing? If you want a country of India, you should specify that... (It's not clear what you mean by "not the numbers in date and time" either, to be honest.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have edited the question !!. I have put the sopln while insertion in map and I am getting country as IN and lang as hi. And for numbers i have also edited the point 2. But yes I would like to point out that for languages there are no country and sometimes i am getting no country at all for "hi".

Comment: Yes, locales form a hierarchy effectively... so for any language I'd expect to see one locale without a country. Basically, if you want the locale to have a language of `hi` and a country of `IN`, that's what you should be testing for...

Comment: thanks. locale hierarchy is the reason then for this behaviour, it would be helpful if you can clarify my doubt for question number 2 and edit1 [why "zh" for no country is working fine but not for "hi"]

Comment: It's a matter of which parts of the data are associated with the language, and which are associated with the country. If you want to look at the raw data involved, go to http://cldr.unicode.org.